# Oracle 11gR2 + RedHat 6.5 cannot start sqlplus

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus, redhat

I cannot start `sqlplus`
I've read everything I found, tried everything and still I am getting "command not found"

I have a user oracle, I did export `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1`

.bash_profile is:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
umask 022
# User specific environment and startup programs

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
export ORACLE_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

and to add $ORACLE_HOME/bin (sqlplus path is inside) in your path

```
PATH=:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```